# Cache network request for one hour in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

In my NodeJs server, I fetch some reference data from an upstream service. I want to cache this value for an hour, so that other parts of my app can do:

```
dataCache.get('productCatalogue')
```

And the cache will either return the in-memory value if the TTL is still valid, *or* if the cached data has exceeded its lifetime, perform a new network request, set the new value in the cache, and then return that new value.

Is there a pre-existing npm package for this sort of thing? It seems like a common use case, but I cannot find anything helpful after performing some basic searches.

Answer (score 0):

Hi memoizee is a great solution https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee.

But if you working with multiple parallel node instances you should look for a memcached or redis solution.